# TensorflowJS: Error: The shape of dict['images'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,224,224,3], but was [400,600,1]

Tags: angular, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm using [mobilenet](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_100_224/classification/1) Neural Network from google to classify images. I'm using angular 6 + TensorFlow.js to build my image classifier app.

I'm trying to follow the steps provided by the [tfjs-converter library readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) and I came up with the following code:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { FrozenModel } from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

export class NeuralNetwork {
    private MODEL_PATH: string = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/model/tensorflowjs_model.pb';
    private WEIGHTS_PATH: string = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/model/weights_manifest.json';
    constructor(){}
    async loadModel() {
        const localModel: FrozenModel = (await tf.loadFrozenModel(this.MODEL_PATH, this.WEIGHTS_PATH));
        let image: any = document.getElementById('cat');

        let pixels =  tf.fromPixels(image, 1);
        let result = localModel.predict(pixels);
        
    }
    async predict(){
        let image: any = document.getElementById('cat');
        debugger;
        this.model.execute({input: tf.fromPixels(image)});
    }
    
}
```

Image HTML Element:

```
<img id="cat" src="http://localhost:4200/assets/images/cat.jpg"/>
```

When I try to execute the `localModel.predict(pixels)` function, I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: The shape of dict['images'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,224,224,3], but was [400,600,1]

I'm a newbie in Tensorflow and TensorFlow.js technologies. Any one know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Its TensOrflow, not "Tensaflow". Sounds like some badass rapper lol

Answer (score 4):

Met the same problem, then found the solution in Github: [Input appears to be wrong shape](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/193)

```
const img = document.getElementById('myimg');
const tfImg = tf.fromPixels(img);
const smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tfImg, [368, 432]);
const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, 'float32');
const t4d = tf.tensor4d(Array.from(resized.dataSync()),[1,368,432,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is a mismatch between the shape defined in the model and the shaped of the input passed to the model. To solve it you have to reshape your input.

However using [tf.reshape](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#reshape) of the input will not work as there is no integer k such as `k*224*224*3` will be equal to `400*600*1`. One can consider slicing of the input image using [tf.slice](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#reshape) so as to keep only the necessary shape for the image.

```
const a = tf.randomNormal([400, 600, 3])
// a has shape [400, 600, 3]
// a cannot be reshaped into [224, 224, 3]
// a can be sliced into [224, 224, 3]
const b = a.slice([0, 0, 0], [224, 224, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur because the model expects a batch of images rather than only one image. To fix it, one can insert the extra dimension using [`expandDims`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/3.0.0/#expandDims).

```
let result = localModel.predict(tf.fromPixels(image).expandDims(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before predicting an image with MobileNet, you need to preprocess the image in a specific way.
Here is how you can do it with TensorFlow.js:

```
let image: any = document.getElementById('cat');

// resize the input image to (224, 224)
let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image).resizeNearestNeighbor([224, 224]).toFloat();
// feature scale tensor image to range [-1, 1]
let offset = tf.scalar(127.5);
tensor = tensor.sub(offset).div(offset).expandDims();
```

And now you can predict the preprocessed image (tensor):

```
let result = localModel.predict(tensor);
```

You can see more related code [here](https://gogul.dev/software/mobile-net-tensorflow-js#31-preprocess-the-input-image).